# ¿Porque cuando uso un Iframe para embeber un video de youtube me sale GET https://www.youtube.com/img/meh7.png 404?

Tags: iframe, nextjs, youtube

Estoy usando iframe para embeber videos de youtube en mi pagina web en nextjs. Pero me sale un erro en la consola del navegador:

> GET https://www.youtube.com/img/meh7.png 404 index.js:1962
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
> https://www.youtube.com/img/meh7.png:1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El iframe que arroja el propio youtube:

```
                  <iframe
                    width="500"
                    height="281"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E7wJTI-1dvQ"
                    title="YouTube video player"
                    frameBorder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowFullScreen
                  />
```

No estoy muy seguro a que se debe. Creo que puede ser las miniaturas aunque no estoy seguro  y menos tengo idea de la solucion.

El video se reproduce bien. No tiene ningun problema excepto por el error que arroja la consola del navegador

¿Porque sale este error? ¿Como soluciono este error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe al servicio de cookie de youtube. Intenta acceder pero no puede. No encontre una forma de desabilitarlo directamente en el Iframe. Pero si uso el paquete **react-lite-youtube-embed** y le configuro la propiedad `noCookie={true}` para desactivar las cookie el error desaparece:

```
                  <LiteYouTubeEmbed
                    id="E7wJTI-1dvQ"
                    title="What’s new in Material Design for the web (Chrome Dev Summit 2019)"
                    noCookie={true}
                  />
```

Para mas informacion: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lite-youtube-embed